# Python OpenCV - get coordinates of borders of elements inside an image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I know my question might sound a little generic but I read a lot of blogs and questions about this and still can't find a solution that get any close to what I'm trying to do. I have the attached sample IG screenshot. My goal is to get the coordinates of the elements I highlighted in green.
Canny edges doesn't seem to do a thing (see also https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_canny/py_canny.html). I read Houg Transform could have helped (https://pysource.com/2018/03/07/lines-detection-with-hough-transform-opencv-3-4-with-python-3-tutorial-21/) but still no luck.
All I would need is a way to get those sections and get their coordinates. If somebody could simply point me out to what technique(s) could help me, that would be helpful.

[image]

Comment: But do you really need it? If you know page's url you can just parse html document.

Comment: @LevZakharov Hi Lev! I'm trying to build an automated test case that tries to rely more on image recognition than on selenium. I see many techniques available with OpenCv and I was wondering if there was a simple way to get those sections.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming they aren't green in the actual data !

The standard way is edge detect (canny or [adaptiveThreshold](https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html)) and then contour. Simplify the contours using [approxPolyDP](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html) and then search the contour list for edges that are the correct length and shape.

Hint: use [cv2.minAreaRect()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html) to check for contours that are likely box size/shape/alignment

You could use probablistic Hough to find line segments, but since the source image is so clean it is easier to just look through the contours

Comment: Thank you very much Martin. I will follow your suggestion and review how to better apply edge detect. If you had any simple spare code you could share that would be hugely appreciated. I will also try to share my code as soon as I get a little closer to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I think you could do the next:

1. Since you have really identified the color of the bounding rectangle you could extract that color from that image into another image (image_green).
2. Now, once you have image_green binarize it (image_bin) i,e. Make an array with two colors, the extracted one and the foreground.

   3. Loop over the image_bin matrix and find all the "corners" that will be all the couple of pixels that match this condition `image_bin[i:i+2,j]/max(image_bin.flatten()) == [1,0]` for any `j` (column), and `i` (row).
   4. Store this coordinates (`[i,j]`). As I mentioned before this values represent 2 corners of the rectangles: The upper-left corner and the lower-right corner.

This approach is done with numpy arrays, so as you might imagine you need to convert the image into an array before step 3. If you still are having problems with this let me know and whenever I have some free time I will post a code that does this.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you Pajarol, appreciated your comment. Thing is, I manually draw those green rectangles since I can't currently find a way to automatically identify and draw them with OpenCv (even though I also admit I started to study openCV just a few days ago).

Answer (score 0):

This kind of border detection can be done using a normal Canny edge detector. We just need to sharpen the image before applying Canny.

Code follows:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('test.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Sharpen the image
kernel = np.array([[-1, -1, -1],[-1, 8, -1],[-1, -1, 0]], np.float32) 
dst = cv2.filter2D(gray, -1, kernel)


#Canny Edge detection
canny = cv2.Canny(dst, 30, 200, 1)

# Find contours
cnts = cv2.findContours(canny, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2:]
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

# Iterate thorugh contours and draw rectangles around contours
for c in cnts:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
   

    cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255,0,255), 1)

#write output
cv2.imwrite('resultimage.png', image)
```